# Container of iFrame not catching events, even during capture phase

Tags: javascript, html

As far as I understand, the `useCapture` argument to `addEventListener` is a way to listen to an event on the parent element before it gets to its children. However, when the child element is an iFrame, this doesn't seem to apply.

In this snippet, I'm listening for a click on the container (using `useCapture` param). The listener fires when clicking outside the iframe, but when I click in the iFrame, the listener doesn't fire. Anyone know why, or have ideas on how I can get the event to fire on the container of the iFrame?

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#container');

container.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log('click: container');
}, true);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <iframe src="" width="300" height="400"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Events on iframe occur inside the iframe `window` which is completely isolated from parent page window.

Such events do not bubble from iframe window to parent window (or parent of iframe element)

If iframe is from a different origin there is no way to get inside it.

If it is same origin you need to add the listener to the document inside the iframe window something like:

```
container.querySelector('iframe').onload = function(){
   this.contentWindow.document.addEventListener...
})
```